# Inject object with constructor that takes a parameter using RoboGuice 2

Tags: java, android, guice, code-injection, roboguice

I am trying out RoboGuice2 for Android (and Guice for that matter) for the first time and am stuck right now.  I have been unable to find an example of how to do this and would love for somebody to show me the correct way with explanation.  I want to @Inject an object that takes a string as a parameter in the constructor.  Example below:

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity {

    @Inject MyObject obj;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate();
       obj.print();
    }
}



public class MyObject {

    private String name;

    @Inject
    public MyObject(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }


    public void print() {
        Log.d("debug", this.name);
    }
}
```

I would be super thankful for an example and explanation of this.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why you even want to manage this object with RoboGuice?  You shouldn't normally (ever) need to or want to pass a parameter in the constructor of an injected object.

Comment: @JamesMcCracken the Object I'm using writes to the file system and can be reused with different file names.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's possible to inject an object with RoboGuice while passing a parameter to its constructor <strike>(and this is certainly not encouraged)</strike>. You might want to consider just changing whatever method you call on that object that writes to the file system to take in that `String` parameter.  If you don't like that option, you can just have a public method to set that parameter before calling the write function.

Ex:

```
@Inject
private MyClass myClass;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate();
    myClass.setFileName("somefile.txt");
    myClass.writeToFile();
}
```

Or

```
@Inject
private MyClass myClass;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate();
    myClass.writeToFile("somefile.txt");
}
```

EDIT:

So after doing some research I'm taking back my statement about this not being encouraged.  From the examples I've seen, your code looks to be be mostly correct. [This Link](http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/google-guice-injecting-primitives-in-constructors/) provided the most complete example I could find.  It seems that there are two options if you want to inject a String into the constructor. you can set it up in you app config bindings (which essentially creates a singleton that you probably don't want).  The second option is to create a Provide (similar to Factory) and use that provider.  Both of these options are outlined in the article above.